# Improper integral with parameters

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to find the values of $\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb{R} $ so the integral :

$$Ι=\int_0^\infty \frac{(\alpha+\beta)+\beta}{2x^2+\beta}=\pi$$

I tried calculating the integral, but I do not know if $\beta$ is positive; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! I want to remind you that it is generally preferred you include context when asking a question here (which can include: where this problem came from, your own attempts, and a *specific* idea as to where you're stuck) - it also lets us help you better! As is, your question is little more than an isolated problem, and thus likely to get a lot of downvotes and closed. Feel free to edit the context into your post though! Here's a useful link: [asking a good question](https://goo.gl/11Cojp).

Comment: Thank you for the advise :)

Comment: @KostasGiatzo I assume this is from some kind of problem you were given. Can you check that you correctly copied it? I'm asking because the term $(\alpha +\beta)+\beta$ strongly suggests to me that there is something missing, an $x$ somewhere.

Comment: it's a problem from my university's calculus 1 book. i double checked it, nothing is missing :)

Comment: @KostasGiatzo Thanks. Then I think the solution below is good to go.

Comment: Don't forget $dx$

Comment: Yeah, my mistake thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\alpha+2\beta}{2x^2+\beta}\mathrm dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot (\alpha+2\beta)\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2+\beta/2}\mathrm dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot (\alpha+2\beta)\cdot\left[\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\beta}}\arctan\left(x\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\beta}}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty}$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: @KostasGiatzo You're welcome